# How do I fix an error containing must return a value?

Tags: c++

just a quick question, I'm not sure why I'm getting this error or how to fix it.

The error is C4176 Box::getParameters: must return a value. It says that it must return the value but I did put the getParameter in there. I've never had this error before and I'm trying to figure out how to fix it. I am currently trying to create classes in my oop class.

```
class Box
{
public:
    double height;//length of the box
    double depth;//depth of the box
    double width;//width of the box

    //Declare Member functions
    double getVolume(void);
    string getParameters(void);

    //Mutators
    void setHeight(double height);
    void setWidth(double width);
    void setDepth(double depth);

    //Accessors
    double getDepth(double depth);
    double getWidth(double width);
    double getHeight(double height);
}; //end class

//member function definitions

double Box::getVolume(void)//get volume will cal and output the volume when called
{
    return height * width * depth;
}
void Box::setDepth(double depth)
{
    depth = 0.01;
}
double Box::getDepth(double depth)
{
    return depth;
}
void Box::setWidth(double width)
{
    width = 0.01;
}
double Box::getWidth(double width)
{
    return width;
}
void Box::setHeight(double height)
{
    height = 0.01;
}
double Box::getHeight(double height)
{
    return height;
}

string Box::getParameters(void)
{
    cout << "\nDepth:" << getDepth(depth) << endl <<
        "Width:" << getWidth(width) << endl <<
        "Height :" << getHeight(height) << endl;
}
int main()
{
    double depth;
    double width;
    double height;
    double volume;
    Box box;

    cout << "Please Enter a Length for your box: ";
    cin >> depth;
    box.setDepth(depth);
    cout << "Please Enter a Width for your box: ";
    cin >> width;
    box.setWidth(width);
    cout << "Please Enter a Height for your box: ";
    cin >> height;
    box.setHeight(height);
    //cout << "\n\n" << box.getParameters();
    volume = box.getVolume();
    cout << "\n\nThe Volume of your box is: " << volume;
    box.getParameters();
    return 0;
}
```

This is my full set of code. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to `return` a value at all possible branches in the function the compiler complained about. Namely in `string Box::getParameters(void)`, the `cout` statement doesn't return anything but just prints text on the terminal.

Comment: You've declared the function like this: `string Box::getParameters(void);` which means it must `return` a `string`.

Comment: You declared your function `getParameters` to return a `std::string`, but you failed to keep that promise. Your implementation does not return anything. Either make that function `void` or return an object of type `std::string`.

Comment: i do have it as void

Comment: @JessicaSimcoe `string Box::getParameters(void)`, the return type is `string`. If it was `void` it would say `void Box::getParameters(void)`. This is the whole issue, you declared a function which should return `void` as returning `string`, that's the reason for the error. I'm sure you had a reason for putting `string` there, but I'm not sure what is was.

Comment: @JessicaSimcoe Actually now I look closer at your code I can see this is something you are confused about. All the getters are wrong as well, this `double Box::getWidth(double width)
{
    return width;
}` should be this `double Box::getWidth()
{
    return width;
}`. You have a parameter to your getters which should not be there (and will mean they don't work).

Comment: @JessicaSimcoe And your setters are wrong as well. This is a very confused code. I'm going to type up a comprehensive answer.

Comment: @john yeah..I've been working on classes for my oop class and I haven't been fully understanding it. The purpose of this assignment is just to calculate the volume of a box using a class

Comment: @JessicaSimcoe Not really, the real point of the class is basic class design, getters, setters (accessors and mutators if you prefer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three different kinds of methods in your class.

First accessors (aka getters) which return a value from the class, these should have no parameter, and a return type for whatever value they return, so for instance

```
// get the height of the box
double Box::getHeight()
{
    return height;
}
```

Mutators (aka setters) which change a value in the class, these should have one parameter that is the new value for the class and a return type of `void` (i.e. they don't return anything). For instance

```
// set the height of the box to h
void Box::setHeight(double h)
{
    height = h;
}
```

Finally there are methods which are neither accessor or mutators, your `getParameters` method is one of those. There are no hard and fast rules about these, it just depends what they do. Your `getParameters` method actually prints something, so `getParameters` is a bad name, it should be called `printParameters`. Since all it does is print something it should not return anything, it also doesn't need any parameters. Here how it should be written

```
// print the box parameters
void Box::printParameters()
{
    cout << "\nDepth:" << getDepth() << endl <<
        "Width:" << getWidth() << endl <<
        "Height :" << getHeight() << endl;
}
```

Comment: it doesnt allow me to do void box::getParameters()  it gives me so many more errors

Comment: declaration is incompatible with <error-type> box::getParameters, incomplete type is not allowed, too few arguments in function call, too few arguments in function call, too few arguments in function call

Comment: @JessicaSimcoe When you change the return type to `void`, you have to change it in both places, in the class and in the definition, that's why it says it's incompatible because you changed it in only one place.

Comment: `class box { ... void getParameters(); ... }; ... void box::getParameters() { ... }` See? `void` in both places.

Answer (score -1):

Keeping the changes simple, use a stringstream instead of stdout and return the string instead of printing to the console

```
string Box::getParameters(void)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "\nDepth:" << getDepth(depth) << endl <<
        "Width:" << getWidth(width) << endl <<
        "Height :" << getHeight(height) << endl;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: Look at those getter functions in the code you copied. You could have addressed that confusion instead of perpetuating it.